# How Can I Save an mp3 recording in one Applicaton and Play Back Recording in Another Acitiviy

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I want to save a recording made in the first activity and then play back the recording in the second activity in my Android App. I think I have everything but I cant seem to find a way to save in the first activity and then be able to access it in the second activity.

Right now, the application crashes because it cant find the file.  I will include parts of the first and second activity for review.

This is from the first Activity where the file path is set

```
 try{
    Log.i(log_tag,"Setting the recorder");
    speaker_recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    speaker_recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    speaker_recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        speaker_recorder.setOutputFile(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/audio_test.3gp");

    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(log_tag,"Recording Settings Failed");
        createTempFile("Status.txt", "COMPLETED-RECORDER FAILED");
    }
    //Prepare the Recorder
    try{
        Log.i(log_tag,"Preparing the Recorder");
        speaker_recorder.prepare();
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(log_tag,"Recording failed");
        createTempFile("Status.txt", "COMPLETED-RECORDER FAILED");
        exit_function();
    }
```

This is from the Second Activity where the file is played back

```
    private void playSound(boolean speakers) {
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mFile = "files" + "/audio_test.3gp";
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(mFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Saving and retrieving file path should be same. Please check for you in second activity it is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first activity, you have:

```
getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/audio_test.3gp"
```

In your second activity, you have:

```
"files" + "/audio_test.3gp";
```

These are not the same. Furthermore, the second one is incorrect. Change the second activity to use the same logic to derive the path as you used in the first activity.

(or, better yet, use `new File(getFilesDir(), "audio_test.3gp")` in both places, rather than use string concatenation)